# Why is the following code susceptible to heap overflow attack

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, buffer-overflow

I'm new to cyber security, and I am trying to understand why the following code is susceptible to a heap overflow attack...

```
struct data {
 char name[128];
};
struct fp {
 int (*fp)();
};
void printName() {
 printf("Printing function...\n");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 struct data *d;
 struct fp *f;
 d = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
 f = malloc(sizeof(struct fp));
 f->fp = printName;
 read(stdin,d->name,256);

 f->fp();
}
```

Is it because of the `read(stdin, d->name, 256)` as it is reading more than the allocated buffer size of `128` for `char name` in `struct data`?

Any help would be great

Comment: Yes, it allows more space to be allocated. But I think it is buffer overflow not heap overflow though

Comment: I was told that it was something to do with the pointers itself. But man, I am super confused and I am new to C and computing in general :( :(

Comment: `read(stdin,d->name,256);` looks wrong.  Sure about using `stdin` here with `read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)`?  (Enable all compiler warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [heap overflow attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_overflow) is similar to a [buffer overflow attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), except instead of overwriting values in the stack, the attacker tramples data in the heap.

Notice in your code that there are two dynamically allocated values:

```
d = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
f = malloc(sizeof(struct fp));
```

So `d` now holds the address of a 128-byte chunk of memory in the heap, while `f` holds the address of an 8-byte (assuming a 64-bit machine) chunk of memory. Theoretically, these two addresses could be nowhere near each other, but since they're both relatively small, it's likely that the OS allocated one larger chunk of contiguous memory and gave you pointers that are next to each other.

So once you run `f->fp = printName;`, your heap looks something like this:

*Note: Each row is 8 bytes wide*

```
     |                        |
     +------------------------+
f -> | <Address of printName> |
     +------------------------+
     |           ▲            |
     |      11 more rows      |
     |       not shown        |
     |                        |
d -> |  <Uninitialized data>  |
     +------------------------+
     |                        |
```

Your initial assessment of where the vulnerability comes from is correct. `d` points to 128 bytes of memory, but you let the user write 256 bytes to that area. C has no mechanism for bounds checking, so the compiler is perfectly happy to let you write past the edge of the `d` memory. If `f` is right next to `d`, you'll fall over the edge of `d` and into `f`. Now, an attacker has the ability to modify the contents of `f` just by writing to `d`.

To exploit this vulnerability, an attacker feeds the address of some code that they've written to `d` by repeating it for all 256 bytes of input. If the attacker has stored some malicious code at address `0xbadc0de`, they feed in `0xbadc0de` to stdin 32 times (256 bytes) so that the heap gets overwritten.

```
     |  0xbadc0de  |
     +-------------+
f -> |  0xbadc0de  |
     +-------------+
     |     ...     |
     |  0xbadc0de  |
     |  0xbadc0de  |
d -> |  0xbadc0de  |
     +-------------+
     |             |
```

Then, your code reaches the line

```
f->fp();
```

which is a function call using the address stored in `f`. The machine goes to memory location `f` and retrieves the value stored there, which is now the address of the attacker's malicious code. Since we're calling it as a function, the machine now jumps to that address and begins executing the code stored there, and now you've got a lovely [arbitrary code execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) attack vector on your hands.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation sir! Just a quick one, what does `f -> fp()` mean? What is `fp()` even ~ like is it a function call of some sort?

Comment: The arrow operator (`->`) is 'dereference and access'. `f` is a pointer to a `struct fp`, so `f->fp` is equivalent to `(*f).fp`, i.e. get the `struct fp` located at memory location `f` and access its member named `fp`. The `fp` member is a pointer to a function, so putting the `()` after it is calling the function it points to.

Comment: More generally, in C function names are treated as pointers to those functions. So `someFunc()` is simply loading `someFunc` as a pointer to a function and then executing it, just like `f->fp()` is loading `f->fp` and executing it. Just like you can store a pointer to data, you can store a pointer to a function and it's effectively the same as calling the function by name.

Comment: I see, its starting to make sense now. So essentially, there was like a buffer overflow in the `read(stdin, d->name, 256)` and as such, some of the memory contents were leaked into the adjacent struct. Then, when the pointer `f` is dereferencing the struct `fp` - then they could instead point it to a different function in the heap ?? I appreciate your help thus far - if you could be so kind to provide a diagram it would be excellent sir. God bless Sir!!

Comment: Precisely! I actually thought about putting in a diagram in the answer, but decided against it originally. I'll go back and edit the answer to include a few now if it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your kind efforts! Regardless, I have accepted your answer. I have proudly learnt something new today, but yes, a diagram would be very much appreciated nonetheless

Comment: BTW how would one go about fixing this vulnerability?

Comment: Just make sure that the program does not accept more data than it has space for. `read(stdin,d->name,128);`